# AKS - enable node local dns

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, coredns, kube-dns

I'm trying to enable nodelocaldns on AKS cluster, however i cannot find a confirmed working way of doing that.

The things i found so far:

- Official docs on enabling it: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/nodelocaldns/
  the problem with it is that according to this discussion it won't work: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1435
- i found this link: https://github.com/curtdept/aks_nodelocaldns/blob/main/nodelocaldns.yaml - it is already filled version of manifest for nodelocaldns, i tried deploying it and it deploys without problem, however i don't know how to check if it works correctly and according to previous point it should not work correctly

So the main question is how to check if nodelocaldns works correctly and point errors in my approach of deploying it?